# COPYING INPUT XML TO OUTPUT by XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

The Below is my input xml

```
<ServiceIncident xmlns="http://b2b.ibm.com/schema/IS_B2B_CDM/R2_2">
    <RequesterID/>
    <ProviderID>INC0011731</ProviderID>
    <ProviderPriority>4</ProviderPriority>
    <WorkflowStatus>NEW</WorkflowStatus>
    <Transaction>
        <Acknowledge>1</Acknowledge>
        <StatusCode>0</StatusCode>
        <Comment>String</Comment>
        <TransactionName>Problem_Submittal</TransactionName>
        <TransactionType>2</TransactionType>
        <TransactionDateTime>2012-10-19T16:05:56Z</TransactionDateTime>
        <TransactionNumber>2012-10-19T16:05:56Z:1ae9b6a79901fc40fa75c64e1cdcc3b4</TransactionNumber>
        <TransactionRouting>MX::ITELLASNINCBRDG</TransactionRouting>
        <DataSource>ServiceNow</DataSource>
        <DataTarget>NASPGR72</DataTarget>
    </Transaction>
</ServiceIncident>
```

My requirement is I need to copy whole input as output except one field in input need to be changed in output.

Below is the code I am using in the xslt to copy input.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:r2="http://b2b.ibm.com/schema/IS_B2B_CDM/R2_2">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>           
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

By using the above code in xslt I am able to copy whole input as output, but in my requirement I need TransactionDateTime should be mapped instead of hardcode value

```
      <TransactionDateTime>2012-10-19T16:05:56Z</TransactionDateTime>
```

I need to use this function in transaction instead of hardcode.
Below is my xslt code but it is not giving output

```
    <xsl:template match="r2:TransactionDateTime">
            <xsl:value-of select="current-dateTime()"/>
     </xsl:template>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [XSLT/X-PATH EXPRESSION](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21697865/xslt-x-path-expression)

Comment: The `current-dateTime()` function is not available in XSLT 1.0 - there's no standard way to get the current time in that version of XSLT, so the answer depends on which XSLT processor you're using (you'll need a processor-specific extension function).

Comment: ... or you'll need to change to a processor that understands XSLT 2.0.

Comment: i tried XSLT 2.0 but it is also not working.

Comment: Well, it does work with XSLT2.0. Could you tell us which processor you are using?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! If you find an answer useful or is best suited for your problem, please accept the answer by clicking the check mark (just below the arrowheads on the left).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add another template that matches the node to be changed, and perform the change in it:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
        xmlns:r2="http://b2b.ibm.com/schema/IS_B2B_CDM/R2_2">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>           
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="r2:DataSource">
    <xsl:copy>Maximo</xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: <xsl:template match="r2:TransactionDateTime">
       <xsl:value-of select="r2:current-dateTime()"/>
    </xsl:template>.I need to get this value in output.

Comment: Could you accept the answer if it solves the first problem? You can post a new question for the new requirement.

Comment: the first one is working but one more field is to be changed in output i.e TransactionDateTime.i applied the same to it but it is not working.

Comment: Alright, you don't need prefix "r2" for current-dateTime(), also, you are missing <xsl:copy> inside the template for TransactionDateTime:
<xsl:template match="r2:TransactionDateTime">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:value-of select="current-dateTime()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

Comment: i tried this code but it is not working it is showing the error as current-date time with arity<1> is not in the in scope function declarations

Comment: Probably you should be using XSLT2.0 for current-dateTime() to be supported.